# How show an image from a class on an image tag

Tags: html, css

I have an image tag in my html:

```
<img class="fruit1" />
```

and the following in my css:

```
.fruit1 {
  background-image: url('./images/apple.png');
}
```

but I am unable to get the actual image to show up, is this the proper way of assigning an image in css and have it show in the view?

Comment: Check the paths and learn more about Paths: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: are you not specifying the mandatory `src` attribute for your image? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.fruit1 {
  background-image: url('./images/apple.png');
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style>

<img class="fruit1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use width and height of image too if you have image as a background image. In that case you shouldnt be having an image tag

```
<div class="fruit1" ></div>


.fruit1 {
  background-image: url('./images/apple.png');
  width: 200px;
   height: 200px
}
```

Showing it just using HTML as you have done;

```
<img class="fruit1" src= "./images/apple.png" width="200px" height="200px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In practice you should use a src attribute if the image is part of the page's content:

```
<img class="fruit1" src="images/apple.png" />
```

Background images are traditionally used to enhance content by replacing appropriate text (often headers):

```
<h2 class="apples">Our Apples</h2>

.apples {
  background-image: url('./images/apple.png');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-indent: -99999px; /* hide the text with a negative text-indent */
}
```